# causal forest and conditional unconfoundness

Tags: machine-learning, causality

I recently read the paper by Kunzel et al. on meta-learners, I encountered there the following statement:

[image]
I fail to understand this statement, as from my understanding, under the assumption of strong ignorability (and the continuous assumptions), for sufficiently large $n$ the leafs in Causal Forests can be treated as a random experiments.

Furthermore, in the Causal Forest paper, the same propensity score is used in the simulation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to me to be a misunderstanding by the authors. Wager and Athey (2018) (the article mentioned as "(8)") rely on an assumption that they call "unconfoundedness", which is sometimes also called "strong ignorability" or "conditional exchanegeability". Notably, the assumption is that treatment is independent of the potential outcomes *conditional on some covariates $X$*. However, to distinguish the scenario when $X$ is the empty set, one might distinguish between "conditional" unconfoundedness, when $X$ is not the empty set, and "unconditional" unconfoundedness, when $X$ is the empty set.

Kunzel et al. (2019) seem to interpret Wager and Athey's assumption of "unconfoundedness" to mean "unconditional unconfoundedness", and therefore claim the method that relies on this assumption not to be valid when conditional unconfoundedness is required, which is the case for the simulation in the quoted text. But that is clearly not how Wager and Athey intended it, since, as you mention, they explicitly mention modeling the propensity score and the assumption is formally stated as being conditional on $X$ where $X$ can be a set other than the empty set. So to me, this is an omission caused by a misunderstanding by Kunzel et al. (2019) about what Wager and Athey's assumption of unconfoundedness means.

#### References

Künzel, S. R., Sekhon, J. S., Bickel, P. J., & Yu, B. (2019). Metalearners for estimating heterogeneous treatment effects using machine learning. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 116(10), 4156–4165. https://doi.org/10.1073/pnas.1804597116

Wager, S., & Athey, S. (2018). Estimation and Inference of Heterogeneous Treatment Effects using Random Forests. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 113(523), 1228–1242. https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2017.1319839